# Instagram client review taking more than 3 days

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

It is taking me more than 3 days for instagram to review my app.

I submitted my app on tuesday. And it is now friday.

How long am I expected to wait?

If my video quality is not good etc. Is instagram just going to leave us hanging forever? How do I know if i am rejected? Is there a support email that I could inquire my instagram review about?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. You probably should contact the service itself.

Comment: @mustaccio Do you know which email I should complain to? https://www.instagram.com/developer/support/ points me to stackoverflow to ask questions ..

Comment: My apps are finally approved after 4 month. Thank god i had other approved applications before this and I just used those instead.

Comment: any latest update for 2019, please?

Comment: @ThinkTwiceCodeOnce I have not tried it recently..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instagram & facebook paused reviewing for new apps for time being, here goes their official statement on the same matter.

**Pause app review:**

We paused app review last week while we implement new changes to our platform.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/03/26/facebook-platform-changes/
```

Answer (score 4):

Facebook and Instagram made major changes to their APIs in an effort to protect your data and privacy.

As per Instagram Help Center :-

> Starting October 1st, only submissions for **basic permissions** on
>   the existing Instagram API will be reviewed. **We will not be
>   accepting submissions for *public_content*, *follower_list*,
>   *comments*, *relationship*, or *likes permission scopes*.** Developers are encouraged to build on the new Instagram Graph API.

So if you are using any of the above mentioned permissions, your app will keep showing **REVIEW STATUS :Pending Review** forever.

[image]

**The new Instagram Graph API**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api

**Here is link with all the details you might want to know.**

https://later.com/blog/instagram-api/

Answer (score 2):

My apps are recently approved. Looks like it took them ~ 4 months

Comment: Congratulations on getting your app approved. I just wanted to know, which all permission did you apply for?

Comment: @AshishPrakash Just basic permission.

Comment: how long it is, during this time, we only can use Sandbox mode that allows added some Insta's users?

Comment: @ThinkTwiceCodeOnce Sandbox only allows so many people. I don't think you can use it in production